# Net Core 3 ILogger Dependency Tracking AppInsights

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog, ilogger

I am using ILogger (`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`) together with application insights. I was wondering when using `BeginScope()` how do I get all the dependencies tracked automatically as part of this, if its even possible?

For example, this code:

```
            using (var scope = this.logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Reference", "HelloWorld" }
            }))
            {
                this.logger.LogDebug("Foo");
                this.logger.LogInformation("Bar.");
                var response = await this.httpClient.PostAsync(..); // dependency tracking
            }
```

This would log the `Reference` field as a custom dimension on the trace however, the dependency entries do not have any custom dimensions against it. Does this have to be done manually or am I missing something?

[image]

Should elaborate, these ^^ are not attached to the tracked dependency entries and I am using a hosted service and hooked up app insights via `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()`

Comment: AFAIK when it is not processed through the Ilogger interface it won't get scope properties added. Dependency tracking is not done using the ILogger interface.

Comment: dependency telemetry dont get the scope properties. Only traces from ilogger get it.

Comment: How do I aggregate the entire dependency chain? As an API you kind of get this for free but I guess as a worker not so much. Enriching the context seems to be the trick I think..

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to group telemetry items together based on the ilogger scope.

The recommended way in application insights to logically group together a bunch of telemetry is by using `StartOperation` API. A simple example is shown below:

```
using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("logical operation to be grouped."))
            {
                using (var scope = logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "Reference", "HelloWorld" }
                    }))
                {
                    logger.LogWarning("Foo");
                    var res = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://bing.com").Result.StatusCode;
                }
            }
```

In this example, all telemetry generated - the 'parent request telemetry', ilogger logs, dependency telemetry, (and anything else within StartOperation), will have the same operationid, and can be queried like shown below:

```
union requests,dependencies,traces 
| where operation_Id == 'daf85c73470f80448394748b5067f6e8'
```

[image: Analytics results]

Also note that in a regular web application, all telemetry generated from the scope of a single request will be automatically correlated together. The above example shows how to manually apply grouping - typically needed in console apps etc.